# Why does NSMakePoint fail in one place and work elsewhere in my program?

Tags: objective-c, function, bezier

This may have an obvious answer that I should see immediately, but I haven't found even an obscure one. Please help. It even makes me want to suspect a bug, but that's unlikely.

I'm trying to make a function that will make a cross at a point zz, and it works partially.

Hovering over the variables in Debug while stopped at a breakpoint at the end of the function shows me the values. I inserted the results z1 and z2 from NSMakePoint as comments on the appropriate lines.

Why does NSMakePoint  fail in one place and work elsewhere in my program?

The first   occurrence should increment zz.x by 10; instead it increments zz.y by 10.
The second  occurrence should decrement zz.x by 10; instead it decrements zz.y by 10.

At the next two occurrences it works OK.

First I tried incrementing x within the argument as shown in the top comment; then I tried incrementing x before the argument as shown. I tried float as well as CGFloat.

What's wrong here?

```
#import "untitled.h"

CGFloat xx,yy;
NSPoint z1,z2, zz; 
    NSBezierPath *path;

void markpoint (NSPoint zz){    //zz=   133.333, 100  OK

//  z2= NSMakePoint(zz.x+10,zz.y);  I tried this first and failed;  
    then I broke out the increment as follows:

    xx=zz.x+10;         //xx=   143.333  OK
    yy=zz.y;            //yy=   100      OK
    z1= NSMakePoint(xx,yy);     //z1=   133.333,110 but should be 143.333,100
    [path moveToPoint:z1];
    z2= NSMakePoint(zz.x-10,zz.y);  //z2=   133.333, 90 but should be 123.333,100
    [path lineToPoint:z2];

    z1= NSMakePoint(zz.x,zz.y+10);  //z1=   133.333, 110 OK
    [path moveToPoint:z1];
    z2= NSMakePoint(zz.x,zz.y-10);  //z2=   133.333,  90 OK
    [path lineToPoint:z2];
}
```

Side issue: I haven't been able to find any place that asserts or denies that float and CGFloat are interchangeable in the Bezier series of functions and NSPoint in Cocoa. Are they?

Comment: I wonder if the problem might be with the way you are declaring NSPoint z1, z2, and zz without initializing them. Generally this is safe for non-pointer variables, but I have had odd problems with NSUInteger and even BOOL variables if I did not explicitly set them to 0 and NO at the start. Some of Objective-C's scalar types seem to act a bit like pointers.

Comment: I suspect that what you're seeing is debugger artifacts, not "reality".  Sometimes, because code gets rearranged, the debugger will return values that don't correspond to the location where you're stopped.  Use NSLog statements to dump the values.

Comment: I put in the NSLog and it yields the same values as Tooltip.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Here's the rest of my response: I initialized to 0,0 and the right values came up! Then I restored to the initial condition by removing those lines,and it still the right values came up! Huh? How did it fix itself?

Comment: When someone gives you a correct answer, click the green checkbox below the post's score. Doing so indicates that answer was the one that solved your problem.

Comment: @user1118321 - Thanks. I believe I've been doing that when justified, but mostly my problems haven't been solved, although I appreciated the attempts to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Always validate input. 
Verify your arguments passed into your function are a relevant value. 
One way is to always initialize to known value at the beginning. This seems like basic C hygiene. 
Only declaring a global variable of a primitive C type will not guarantee it has any value but only that some space in memory is set aside for an amount the size of that type at a specific memory

CGFloat is a typedef declared in a header file. 
You need to become familiar with how to look up these things in headers as it will become an invaluable skill. 
XCode makes it super easy, but you also need to read the Xcode help.. ;)

CGFloat is a double or a float depending on the hardware. 
So, it's an ifdef typedef ...